# Login as TeamsServer system user

Tags: server.app

How can I login as the _teamsserver user? I have sudoed and set the passwd for teamsserver, but it does not take it when I use the login command. I need to see the output of some scripts as they are run by teamsserver, and verify that teamsserver has the correct permissions and utilities available.

Comment: I usually just use `sudo` to look at any log files (or `sudo -s` to get a root shell), would this work for you as well?

Comment: No, I can do that, but I need to run a script as teamsserver. I need to make sure the teamsserver user has all the correct utilities and permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just look at log files etc. I usually use either

```
sudo less /path/to/log/file
```

or (in case I need root access longer) run `sudo -s` to get a root shell.

To run processes as another user you can use

```
sudo -H -u _teamserver cmd-to-run
```

And finally, to simulate a login there is

```
sudo -H -u _teamserver -i
```

Comment: Actually, it seems to work, but it is still not running as teamsserver. When I check (echo $ENVVAR) an environment variable that I know is set in teamsserver, it does not show

Comment: `-i` reads `.profile` from the home directory of the user, in this case from `/var/teamserver`