# number of pg_ctl processes keep increasing on macos High Sierra

Tags: macos, performance

After approximately one day of system uptime, my MacBook Pro runs extremely slow. I am running macOS 10.13.5 and Activity Monitor shows ~70% idle cpu usage and the memory pressure is on green but there are what seems like thousands of pg_ctl processes running by the user _teamsserver. With a restart, the number of processes slowly increase back to a large number and slows the computer again. Activity monitor shows the number of processes to be ~2100.

How can I determine what the _teamsserver and pg_ctl are so I disable them or what's launching these?

Comment: Is your laptop using [Insider's FontAgent® TeamServer](https://www.insidersoftware.com/fontservers/teamserver/) font sharing software? If so, make sure you have the most recent version installed.

Comment: I do not have this software installed.

Comment: Is the user _teamsserver or _teamserver?

Comment: Sorry you are correct, it is _teamsserver

Comment: Have you ever installed macOS Server on this MBP? Some _teamsserver questions at AskDifferent [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113837/library-server-wiki-database-xpg-consuming-huge-amount-313gb-of-disk-space/) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104134/login-as-teamsserver-system-user) may give you some clues as to what's going on.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling the OS and the problem was solved. Thank you.